# How to navigate to another folder's page in razor page?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, frontend, navigation, razor-pages

I work with ASP.NET Core Razor pages. Structure of my project is head folder called `Pages`. In it, I have a lot of Razor pages. In `/Pages` I have subfolder called `Reader` with one Razor page called `AddReader`. I want to navigate from `/Pages` Razor page to `/Pages/Reader/AddReader`, but it does not find the path.

I tried

```
href='/Pages/Reader/AddReader'
asp-page='/Pages/Reader/AddReader'
```

I pasted and the full path of page but it did not work again. This is in the frontend.

My code is:

```
<div>
    <a class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' asp-page="/Pages/Reader/AddReader" style="background-color:yellow;color:black;text-align:left;margin-left:200px;width:400px;text-align:center">Стани читател</a>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to navigate from /Pages/razor page to /Pages/Reader/AddReader

Try to a  link in your Pages/razor page cshtml:

```
<a asp-page="/Reader/AddReader">AddReader</a>
```

Comment: Hi@Атанас, any update ? If my answer help you solve the problem ? If not, could you please follow up to let me know ?

Comment: Hi.Thank you for your answer but it do not work again.There is a padlock next to each of my folders.May be this is the reason.When i click it redirects me to the project home page.

Comment: @Атанас , my test demo don't have a padlock next to each of my folders. And it's ok. Do you add a padlock next to each of your folders for some reason ?

Comment: No it is automatically.When i create the folder there is not padlock but when i add razor page in it the padlock appears next to the folder.I checked settings but did not find something about that.

Comment: I read that padlock is for secured transfer in internet and page can be only read.I thing i cn not remove it and it is not ok to remove it.

Comment: @Атанас  It's strange. I add razor page don't meet the padlock .  How do you add the razor page ?